# Careers profile strips leading numbers from tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

Looking at my Careers profile today, I noticed that I apparently am in the top 10% for the [d](/questions/tagged/d) tag.

[image]

I never knew I was that good, especially given the fact that I don't have any activity within this tag. Perhaps I have qualities that are hidden even from me.

However, looking for a more plausible explanation, it seems to me that this should actually be the [3d](/questions/tagged/3d) tag.

[image]

In fact, when for a test I add the [3d](/questions/tagged/3d) tag under the "Technologies" section within an "Experience", upon saving it turns into the [d](/questions/tagged/d) tag. When subsequently editing this, it appears indeed that the '3' has been stripped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, this was a bug and should be resolved now. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now I'll have to really learn D... ;)